# How to generate pseudorandom no. easily?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

i am using `seed` and  functions like  `srand()` or `random()`  to generate numbers   from just `0 to 5` but i  need an easier method that makes also easy to  find `seed` by feeding array. Please suggest one

Comment: What is difficult about using `rand()`?

Comment: If you are using C++ I would suggest using the new [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) facilities.  You can get better randomness and after writing a convenience function it becomes really simply to call a function and give it range to return from.

Comment: Finding seed by feeding array

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _finding the seed_? Reverse-engineering the initial seed value given a set of consecutive random numbers is only possible in limited cases.

Comment: Please pick a language

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want a PRNG (which does by definition practically not allow to determine the next value), with the special attribute that it is always possible to determine the preceding value, if a sequence of a certain minumum length is known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example that generates 10 evenly distributed random numbers in the range -42 to 42 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <random>
int main()
{
    std::random_device seed_device;
    std::mt19937 engine(seed_device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(-42, 42);
    auto rnd = std::bind(distribution, std::ref(engine));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "random number: " << rnd() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See also:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `std::bind` instead of a lambda?  You don't really need a `std::function` object and the type erasure that comes with it here.

Comment: @NathanOliver No reason except that I just grabbed an old example I had previously written for another purpose. A lambda would work equally well.

Comment: OK.  Just checking.